# Describe regular language

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I have an homework question that it let me out of my depth. It say: Given the next regular expression `(1 + 0)*(01)0*` describe with your own words the language which denote and give four examples with more than 6 characters. I could give the 4 examples but i don't know how describe the language

The examples that i given are:

string1 := {1010000}

string2 := {1010010}

string3 := {0101000}

string4 := {10010100}

Answer (score 0):

The language is the set of all words that contain the string $01$ and have a $0$ immediately before the last $1$ in the string.